# R DataTable Convert Data To Mean and Quantiles

Tags: r, data.table

```
data = data.frame(a = runif(100), b = runif(100), c = runif(100), d = runif(100))
```

If I wish to convert to a mean of all a, b, c and d I can do this:

```
setDT(data)
dataMEAN <- data[, lapply(.SD, mean)]
```

But What if I am searching for the mean and quantiles such as

```
quantile(data$a, probs=c(.10,.90))
```

How can I do this all at once in data.table and fill in such a data.table like this:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can `melt` the data to 'long' format, grouped by 'variable', get the `mean` in a `list`, concatenate with the `list` column created with `quantile`

```
library(data.table)
out <- melt(setDT(data))[, c(list(MEAN = mean(value)), 
      as.list(quantile(value, probs = c(.10, .90)))), variable]
out
#   variable      MEAN        10%       90%
#1:        a 0.4903088 0.04842401 0.8790265
#2:        b 0.4890356 0.11788974 0.9221995
#3:        c 0.4890958 0.12364468 0.8670124
#4:        d 0.4638097 0.06690734 0.9448844

setnames(out, 3:4, c('LOWER', 'UPPER'))
```

---

Or use `setNames` within the `melt`

```
melt(setDT(data))[, c(list(MEAN = mean(value)), 
  setNames(as.list(quantile(value, probs = c(.10, .90))), 
       c('LOWER', 'UPPER'))), variable]
```

Comment: that is 100% what I am trying to do. Thank you again akrun! is it possible to change the variable names in the melt function, otherwise I get column names 10% and 90% I can do it afterwards but am just wondering

Comment: @bvowe you can change it with `setnames` or `names` updated